# How to access error message in the front end sent by the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my node backend, this is how I send the error message to the front end:

```
catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json("UNEXPECTED ERROR. Please try again later.");
  }
```

How do I access the error message in the backend? Is this correct?

```
catch (err) {
  err.response.data;
}
```

Comment: Console.log the `err`... It most probably is `err.message` you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the error message like: `error.message`

I have tried in typescript this worked for me.

```
try {
    throw new Error("UNEXPECTED ERROR. Please try again later.");
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error!.message);
    return res.status(400).send(error!.message);
  }
```